# how call custom module block in template file using layout configration file in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

friends
i have created custom module ,in which i have crated blocks  .i want use this block in template  but this is not work.

This is my config file :-

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
      <config>
        <modules>
          <CustomModule_SocialLogin>
             <version>1.0.0</version>
          </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
       </modules>
       <frontend>
            <routers>
              <customer>
                <args>
                  <modules>
                    <CustomModule_SocialLogin before="Mage_Customer">CustomModule_SocialLogin_Customer </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
                 </modules>
              </args>
           </customer>
           <sociallogin>
             <use>standard</use>
             <args>
                <module>CustomModule_SocialLogin</module>
                <frontName>sociallogin</frontName>
            </args>
          </sociallogin>
       </routers>
       <layout>
         <updates>
            <CustomModule_SocialLogin module="CustomModule_SocialLogin">
                <file>CustomModule/sociallogin.xml</file>
            </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
        </updates>
     </layout>
</frontend>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <CustomModule_SocialLogin>
            <class>CustomModule_SocialLogin_Block</class>
        </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <CustomModule_SocialLogin>
            <class>CustomModule_SocialLogin_Model</class>
        </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
    </models>
    <helpers>
        <CustomModule_SocialLogin>
            <class>CustomModule_SocialLogin_Helper</class>
        </CustomModule_SocialLogin>
    </helpers>  
  </global>
 </config>
```

My block file  -:

```
         class  CustomModule_SocialLogin_Block_Qa extends   Mage_Core_Block_Template{
            public function getText()
            {
             $name='test';
             return $name;     
            }
        }
```

custom module layout update file   :-

```
   <layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
        <reference name="content" translate="label">
          <block type="custommodule_sociallogin/qa" name="SocialLogin.qa"  template="CustomModule/SocialLogin/questionans.phtml" />
        </reference> 
     </default>
   </layout>
```

my template file :-

```
<?php
   echo $this->getText()->toHtml();
   //echo $this->getText();
?>
```

Please help me to solve this error .

Comment: Please be describe your error as detailed as possible. "It did not work" is too general and makes it almost impossible to help you.

Comment: Template page not added in layout .it does not show any error, i have use Template Path Hints from system->configuration->developer .I think error will be in  [ block type="custommodule_sociallogin/qa" ] . My block is CustomModule_SocialLogin_Block_Qa  . i am confuse in  block type naming .

Answer (score 2):

You need to correct your module layout file. I have corrected the block type.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <default>
    <reference name="content" translate="label">
      <block type="sociallogin/qa" name="SocialLogin.qa"  template="CustomModule/SocialLogin/questionans.phtml" />
    </reference> 
 </default>
```

In template file :-

```
<?php
echo $this->getText();
?>
```

Comment: Hello @Ramesh Kumar, unfortunately I had to reject this edit suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9972318 . There is no need to edit tags into titles; SO is set up so that search engines will already see tags.